# Google Drive login before user login possible?

Tags: windows-7, google-drive

***NOTE: the answers proposed are for Windows Server 2003. Even the one claiming Windows 7 posted in 2012 appears to fail in 2014. I have tried them and they do not work for Windows 7. This question has not been answered yet.***

***If you have not tested in Windows 7, please do not post an answer. The answers given are not for this version of windows and are not compatible.***

That said I do appreciate the suggestions...

I have a Windows 7 machine that needs to have a fresh boot weekly. This part works fine. The issue is that Google Drive needs to be accessible even if I have not logged into the box. It is attached to a user account so the act of logging in enables it. Is there a way to have the system log into Google Drive on its own at boot time? I attempted to have Windows 7 boot into a specified account on its own, but it did not activate the drive.

The option to start with the computer was chosen, it did not start with the computer but with the account, meaning a username and password is still required to be manually entered.

[I am using 32-bit Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1]

UPDATE:

I am going to attempt a different method of syncing files instead of google drive, it may be possible that the 'server' solutions do not equate to Windows 7 deployment. (EG: this question may not have a working answer, or one has not been found yet.)

Comment: You could try setting [Start Google Drive automatically when you start your computer](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375018?hl=en).

Comment: I will test this, I did in fact choose the 'automatically start' option to begin with, it does not sync until I log in with a manual password. It is intended to attach to an account which makes sense. If the other page works I will be happy.

Comment: In the thread pointed by @Alex, I'm not sure that the accepted answer is the best. I would favor trying [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/728866/8672).

Comment: In the Windows 2003 answers, that one regarding srvany.exe apparently is incompatible with Windows 7. It created a service, and the password worked, but then it stated that the service could not start (no reason why). Trying the other proposed solutions.

Comment: The task scheduler method did not work either unfortunately. It appears there is no solution for Windows 7 in the Windows Server 2003 answer.